# Jfrog Xray API to retrieve reports

Tags: api, report, jfrog-xray

I'm trying to retrieve the `vulnerabilities` and `licenses` reports (ideally in .csv format) using Xray API.
Before coding in groovy - trying to make it working using curl.

Reading documentation, but can't find detailed explanation and useful examples.

For example, running the following:

`curl -X POST  -u<user>:<pswrd> -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"checksums":["1b25b...."],"report_type":"license"}' "https://<my-xray-server>/xray/api/v1/summary/artifact"`

does return for specified (by checksum) artifact the list of both

- issues (vulnerabilities)
- licenses
  In the same Json report contest.

Despite I explicitly specified **"report_type":"license"** to get licenses report only.
Is there a way to retrieve vulnerabilities/licenses reports separately?
Is there a way to get those reports in the .csv format (instead of default json)?
TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You should work with the [Xray REST API docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Xray+REST+API).

More specifically, [create a vulnerabilities report](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Xray+REST+API#XrayRESTAPI-GenerateVulnerabilitiesReport) or a [due diligence report](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Xray+REST+API#XrayRESTAPI-GenerateDueDiligenceReport) (licenses) and then [export](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Xray+REST+API#XrayRESTAPI-Export) it in the desired format (CSV is supported).

Example of how the commands would actually look

1. Create the report

```
curl -u<user>:<password> -X POST https://server/xray/api/v1/reports/vulnerabilities -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '<json block>'
```

2. Export the report

```
curl -u<user>:<password> -X GET https://server/xray/api/v1/reports/export/{id}?file_name=vuln_report_1&format=csv
```

Comment: Thanks @Eldad! I definitely was looking to those API docs. And they are not sufficient (in my opinion). Looking to those docs I can't figure out how to create a `curl` command. Let's say I want to generate a CSV `due diligence report` for artifact `myArtifact1.tar.gz` in the repo `max_artifacts`. No additional filters needed. What would be an example of such curl?

Comment: Also example of monitoring report status (when from `pending` it's switched to `completed` (or similar) would be helpful.

Comment: You are right. The docs are poorly formatted. I know there is effort to improve this. The general syntax would be `curl -u<user>:<password> -X POST https://server/xray/api/v1/reports/vulnerabilities -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '<json block>'`.

Comment: Can we generate the reports dynamically by having scope of defined repos and builds using azuredevops pipeline? The API call Json is seems bit difficult to modified by the pipeline parameters or variables of repos and builds

Comment: Try looking at https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/scanning-files-on-the-local-file-system and see if it helps. Basically, using the JFrog CLI to trigger Xray actions.